# php file_get_contents() fails in docker container

Tags: docker

file_get_contents() fails in my docker container.  tried the same code on hosted website and it works fine.  After googling it seems the problem is that my docker container DNS cannot resolve to the "outside" world.
I added a DNS entry in to my docker yml and rebuilt the container. still no joy.

Working code that fails in docker container

```
$UserIP = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$IPGeoLocation = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://www.iplocate.io/api/lookup/'. $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] .'')); 
$Data['IPGeoLocation'] = $IPGeoLocation->city .', '. $IPGeoLocation->postal_code;
```

cut down of my docker yml

```
version: "2.1"
services:
  nginx:
    image: lscr.io/linuxserver/nginx:latest
    container_name: nginx

    dns:
      8.8.8.8
      1.1.1.1

    environment:
      - PUID=1000
      - PGID=100
      - TZ=Etc/GMT
    volumes:
      - /volume1/docker/devfiles:/config

    ports:
      - 8080:80
      - 8081:443
    restart: unless-stopped
```